How can I manually create an UploadFile in FastAPI?
Background
I am trying to write tests for my FastAPI application. I have an object, ImageRecord, which uploads an image to S3. Here's the method signature:
async def upload_image(file: UploadFile, s3_client=None) -> 'ImageRecord':

This method is called by the API logic (i.e. the actual @app.post function) to upload an object. I want to test this method by uploading an image file to moto - so a mocked S3 bucket. This method, in ImageRecord, expects an UploadFile because it is called from the function - so I can't just pass in the bytes. Additionally, I call file.content_type in my code to get the content type.
The Issue
I can't create an instance of my actual API and call it because, in order to inject the mocked S3 object, I have to call the Python method from ImageRecord directly - not via a HTTP request. However, this means that I need to create the UploadFile object manually. Here is how I am creating it:
contents = open("resc/valid_image.jpg", "rb").read()
upload_file = UploadFile(filename="test_image.jpg", file=io.BytesIO(contents))

However, when I upload it to ImageRecord, I get the error:
Invalid type for parameter ContentType, value: None, type: <class 'NoneType'>, valid types: <class 'str'>

Because upload_file.content_type is None. In real API code, when FastAPI creates the file, the source code says:

The content type of the request, from the headers

But my manually created file has no headers, and does not accept a content_type argument in init.
TL;DR
A manually created FastAPI.UploadFile has no content_type, because that must be inferred from the headers. Is there any way to create an UploadFile instance with a content_type for tests? Or do I need to refactor my code so that it infers the content type from the contents, and skips UploadFile.content_type alltogether?

Wouldn't changing upload_image to just take a file-like object be easier? That way you remove the binding to it being an actual UploadFile, and you could use it regardless of whether it's an uploaded file, a file on disk, a disk stream in memory, or just a test?

I had the same issue and managed to resolve it by setting the headers and specifying the

content-type

in the headers object, before passing it to UploadFile:
headers = {
            'content-type': mime_type
          }
media_file = UploadFile(file=file_content, filename=file_name, headers=headers)

Now calling media_file.content_type correctly returns the content type for the file.

Thank you, but I need to specifically create an UploadFile myself rather than creating one via the FastAPI server. Glad this solved your issue though.

Just to clarify, I am creating a UploadFile object by reading a local file, converting the file content with BytesIO, manually creating a headers variable as shown above and then creating a UploadFile object. I'm not using my FastAPI endpoints to do this. After creating this object it is passed to a upload_file method, which expects a UploadFile object, to be uploaded to a Google Cloud Storage bucket.
Is this not similar to what you are trying to do?

My bad, didn’t read carefully enough. Thank you!

Workaround
Unfortunately, the content_type field of UploadFile has no setter - because it can only be inferred from the headers. However, writing a wrapper around it allows one to specify content_type in init. For example:
class TestUploadFile(UploadFile):
    def __init__(self, filename: str, file: io.BytesIO, content_type: str):
        super().__init__(filename=filename, file=file)
        self._content_type = content_type

    @property
    def content_type(self): # Override content_type
        return self._content_type

Initiate this file in your tests instead of UploadFile. For example:
contents = open("resc/valid_image.jpg", "rb").read()
    upload_file = TestUploadFile(filename="test_image.jpg", file=io.BytesIO(contents), content_type="image/jpeg")

And, since its superclass is UploadFile, all methods will work like a normal UploadFile. Note: this should only be used for tests, because the only way to specify the content_type is in init - but can be used the same way as UploadFile - plus the ability to specify content type.
Caveat
This will work for tests - but there is no way to initialize UploadFile directly. A subclass with a custom property is required.
